# Special sorting of symbols in a layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, symbology, sorting

I have this feature class

[image]

I would like it to be :

First

Second

Third

Fourth

Unsuitable

Water

No data

The only was I know how to sort it in the Symbology tab is alphabetically. I know I can also rearrange them in the legend in Layout View. Should I put Water and No data in separate layers and label the classes with numbers instead? Or is there away to sort them the way I like?

Comment: Did you use buttons on the right size in Layer properties / Symbology?

Comment: @aldo_tapia I didn't know what you meant at first, but after reading Alex's answer, I understand. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add symbology to your layer, the labels will be sorted alphabetically by default. You can specify the order of listing of labels in the `Layer Properties > Symbology tab`. Select a row and use the up and down arrows buttons to reorder the list.

On the image below, I've moved `California` to be the first item in the list.

[image]

You can also create a new field (called something like `LabelField` to calculate the values that will be used for symbology and symbols order). Mind that the sorting happens alphabetically anyway, so if you have more than 9 items, the order would be `1 Arizona, 10 Georgia, 11 Hawaii` and so forth.

Comment: Your first suggestion worked, thanks! I don't understand the LabelField thing, though.

Comment: Great! The `LabelFIeld` I was talking about: you create a new field in your feature class and calculate it to have values that would let you sort your classes in the TOC using the order you want. Take a look at this Help topic: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/tables/making-field-calculations-making-simple-field-calc.htm